# Aeson : generics with default values

Tags: haskell, aeson

Today I wanted to solve next problem.

Assume that we have typeclass `DataWithDefault` defined as

```
class DataWithDefault a where
  defaultValue :: a
```

And we have data `Example` defined as

```
data Example =
  Example { field1 :: Text
          , field2 :: Text
          } deriving (Show)

instance DataWithDefault Example where
  defaultValue = Example "Hello" "World"

instance FromJSON Example where
  parseJSON (Object v) =
    Example <$> v .:? "field1" .!= field1 defaultValue
            <*> v .:? "field2" .!= field2 defaultValue
  parseJSON _ = mzero

instance ToJSON Example where
 toJSON (Example f1 f2)  =
    object [ "field1" .= f1
           , "field2" .= f2
           ]
```

I know that Aeson uses Generics to derive `FromJSON` and `ToJSON` instances automatically, but I can't figure out how to make it derive `FromJSON` instance with default values for fields that are not represented in given json. Is it possible to do using generics? Actually I don't ask you a final solution, but maybe some clue?

**Update**

Let me add more information about the problem.

Suppose now that you need to update your `Example` data and now it defined as

```
data Example =
  Example { field1 :: Text
          , field2 :: Text
          , field3 :: Int
          } deriving (Show)
```

So you want to update `DataWithDefault` instance declaration

```
instance DataWithDefault Example where
  defaultValue = Example "Hello" "World" 12
```

And what I want to do is not to write

```
instance FromJSON Example where
  parseJSON (Object v) =
    Example <$> v .:? "field1" .!= field1 defaultValue
            <*> v .:? "field2" .!= field2 defaultValue
            <*> v .:? "field3" .!= field3 defaultValue
  parseJSON _ = mzero
```

And want to derive such instance definition automatically. And more importantly, I want to do it not only for `Example`, but for `DataWithDefault a`.

**Update 2**

The point of combining `.:?` and `.!=` is to get as much as possible fields from given json and set every missing field to it's default value. So when we pass

```
{ "field1" : "space", "field2" : "ship" }
```

I want my new example be not `field1 = Hello; field2 = World; field3 = 12`, but `field1 = space; field2 = ship; field3 = 12`.

Comment: Couldn't you do `fromMaybe defaultValue $ decode jsonContents`?

Comment: If you're making your own typeclass you might consider using instead `Data.Default` to get instances for a lot of structures

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of making Aeson do it, just use a newtype for what they were designed for:

```
newtype DefaultJSON a = DefaultJSON { unDefaultJSON :: a }

instance (FromJSON a, DataWithDefault a) => FromJSON (DefaultJSON a) where
    parseJSON v = DefaultJSON <$> (parseJSON v <|> pure defaultValue)
```

Then you can do

```
> decode "{}" :: Maybe (DefaultJSON Example)
Just (DefaultJSON {unDefaultJSON = (Example {field1 = "Hello", field2 = "World"}})
```

This is a little different than what you asked, it provides a default value in case parsing fails, but not a default value for each field in case that individual field is missing.

Comment: well yes, I could do so, but it would be great if it will set default value for each missing field.

Comment: oh, and I am not expecting it from Aeson, I just want to figure out if solution for my problem exists (reasonable one) :D

Comment: @d12frosted I wrote [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26260503/839246) answer the other day that is a good solution to a single field, but I would not consider it reasonable for all fields in a record obviously.  Maybe it can give you some ideas?